# How to prevent the pasting of special characters into an input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

I want to prevent users from using special characters, I can already prevent the user from typing these characters, but I'm also trying to prevent pasting of special characters. 
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wnjgLj62/2/)

Please note: I'm allowing Cyrillic, latin and turkic characters.

JS:

```
$('input').bind('input', function() {
  var c = this.selectionStart,
   r = /[^a-zA-Za-åa-ö-w-я 0-9/@!"#¤?¨'_.,]/,gi
   v = $(this).val();
 if(r.test(v)) {
 $(this).val(v.replace(r, ""));
  c--;
  }
 this.setSelectionRange(c, c);
});
```

Comment: search `regex unicode range`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.inputClass')..keypress(function (e) {
      //Change Regex according to Your need to allow
      var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which:e.charCode);
      if (!regex.test(key)){
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
   });
   $('.inputClass').bind("keyup paste",function(e){
       var txtValue = $(this).val();
       //Change your Regex according to your need to block while pasting
       if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(txtValue) == false){
           e.preventDefault();    
       }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. See the link for **Demo** [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnjgLj62/26/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('input').on("keyup paste",function(e) 
  {
    var txtValue = $(this).val();

    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(txtValue) == false) 
    {
       $(this).val('');    
    }
  });
});

$('input').bind('keypress', function (event)
{
   var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
   var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which:event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) 
{
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Nice, But this won't allow Cyrillic or turkic characters.

Comment: That won't allow *any* characters to be pasted.

Comment: @paveen Thanks, but that wasn't the question. :)

Comment: @Kez you don't want to allow pasting for special characters alone right?

Comment: i have changed my code ..please check and tell me for your turkish letters.